# Problem with Flutter on Visual Studio code when using "just_audio" to run local audio assets

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio code to run Flutter program that use "`just_audio`" to use audio files from local assets.

**When running "`flutter pub add just_audio`" I have errors on dependencies and have this error:**

> "just_audio" is already in "dependencies". Will try to update the constraint.
> Resolving dependencies...
> leak_tracker 10.0.0 (10.0.4 available)
> leak_tracker_flutter_testing 2.0.1 (3.0.3 available)
> leak_tracker_testing 2.0.1 (3.0.1 available)
> meta 1.11.0 (1.12.0 available)
> test_api 0.6.1 (0.7.0 available)
> vm_service 13.0.0 (14.0.0 available)
> Got dependencies!
> 6 packages have newer versions incompatible with dependency constraints.
> Try `flutter pub outdated` for more information.

---

**When running the program I have the following in debug Console:**

> Multidex support is required for your android app to build since the number of methods has exceeded 64k. See https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#enabling-multidex-support for more information. You may pass the --no-multidex flag to skip Flutter's multidex support to use a manual solution.

> Flutter tool can add multidex support. The following file will be added by Flutter:
> android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/app/FlutterMultiDexApplication.java
> cannot prompt without a terminal ui
> Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

---

I have tried other packages other than "`just_audio`" and seems that same problem I'm stuck in.

Extensions versions used in Visual Studio Code:

- Dart: v3.83.20240220
- Flutter: v3.82.0

I don't have so much experience in Flutter and I am in the entry level. Appreciate your support.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the compileSdkVersion solved my problem.

I changed `compileSdkVersion` in android/app/build.gradle

From

```
 compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
```

TO

```
compileSdkVersion 33
```

and the error gone.

**EDIT:**

I got the same issue when i change the compile sdk to 34 which flutter recommended me because i was using url_launcher and video_player which use compileSdk 34. and as i changed the compileSdkVersion to 34 i got the same issue again and that i solved by changing the `minSdkVersion` to 24 from 21

Change From

```
minSdkVersion 21
```

To

```
minSdkVersion 24
```

Thanks to [Johnyp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6065375/johnyp)

Comment: first change the `minSdkVersion` hope it will work for you if it didn't then change the `compileSdkVersion` also that will solve your problem.

Comment: I'm just using Android Studio to use virtual device to run program written on Visual Studio Code.
When I run using chrome browser the code succeed.
I have tried to use virtual device running APIs 28, 33, 34 and same problem.

Comment: did you tried changing the `mindSdkVersion` in build.gradle?

Comment: I think build.gradle is in "Android Studio Project".

Comment: check your app level `build.gradle`

Comment: I can finally solve the problem.
I have tried another package "audioplayers" and have also errors. Then I have updated Visual Studio Code, and this lead to a storage error. Then I have changed the storage of the virtual device, and it works!!!

I really appreciate your efforts to help me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I can finally solve the problem. I have tried another package "audioplayers" and have also errors. Then I have updated Visual Studio Code, and this lead to a storage error. Then I have changed the storage of the virtual device, and it works!!!